# error in code ( asp.net )

Tags: asp.net

Why this code does not work?

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    btnOk1.Visible = true;
    btnOk2.Visible = false;
}
else
{
    btnOk1.Visible = false;
    btnOk2.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about where you are calling this code from? Page Load? Button Event? During Postback?

Comment: What do you mean by its not working, can you post all your code and describe your problem ??

Comment: Is your else part is executed every time ?

Comment: There's not nearly enough information here for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

firstly: where you call this code .more clarification .

secondly: make sure that the property  `autoPostBack = true;`

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that you expect this code to change the state of your two buttons at the moment you choose an item in the dropdown.  Since your code is server-side, that won't actually happen until you submit the page.

I suggest you try a little JavaScript or jQuery instead.  Then your code will run in the browser, prior to postback, and you will see the state of the buttons change immediately.